# Angular Cookies with .net Core

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, cookies

I have an asp.net core web api and angular front-end. The application sends a post to a controller action on the web api and authenticates the user.

My question is whats the correct way to return a authentication cookie and eventually store? I've found this [cookie library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) which seems to serve my purposes just fine. Some more specific questions are:

- What name should the cookie have? Is a GUID fine? I have heard about encryption, or just a session id. The cookie will be send only by HTTPS
- How am i creating the cookie in the asp.net core? I get a username password and simply autheticate the results with an SQL server, and i dont want the user to sign in every time
- How do i retrieve cookie from the http post request? I am using httpClient to post to the url. I know how to send it back using http interceptor with angular.

Thank you for taking the time to even read this long post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing I should warn you that working with cookie-based authentication can give you a lot of problems:

- Because of CORS restriction, your app should be placed on the same domain as your web API
- For mobile apps, this cookie approach won't work at all

If you ok with this lets start solving your problems:

1. Yes, ngx-cookie-service is quite a good library. I used it on some
   complex projects
2. Implementing your own auth solution is not a simple task because you need to correctly implement a hash algorithm, cookies and session management (I assume that you going to have stateful web api if you start looking at cookies based auth), so I recommend using IdentityServer - it is a really simple library for quick auth implementation. For most projects out of the box set up is suitable. If you used this library you don't need to manipulate cookies on your own.

> What name should the cookie have?

It doesn't matter

> How do I retrieve cookie from the http post request?

Cookies are saved automatically by browser

Also, I found a good example of implementation Angular + .NET Core Web API Cookie Based auth [here](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/07/18/secure-an-asp-net-core-web-api-using-cookies/)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have solved CORS problem and it's just a web application. I was baffled by it. I will check the identity server.